# Password login show Div localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Is there any way to make localstorage work to always show the contents of the "Lorem ipsum" div, when login is successful?

This way, when someone enters the password correctly, the content would always be visible, and stored with localstorage, and if it is also possible to hide the password field and the login button...

what I have achieved so far:

```
    jsfiddle.net/thvinic/697bcq2t/1
```

password in the exemple is 12345

help me please!
Thank you for any help!

Comment: have you tried? your code has no mentioned of localStorage, so, can't really guess exactly what you want. please put code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from the question you are looking to check localStorage for the value in the div after a successful "login". If that is the case, when you hit the if statement you can set the hiddenValue into localStorage using the localStorage api setItem()

```
     // No need to add a "show" class. Just remove the "hidden" class.
     div.classList.remove('hidden');
     localStorage.setItem('hiddenValue', div.innerHTML);
```

To check when the page loads if you've "logged in" with this local storage variable, you can then set up a small function to call to check for the local storage item, and perform any logic you need (hiding the input and button and showing the div)

```
function setupPage() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('hiddenValue')) {
    input.classList.add('hidden');
    btn.classList.add('hidden');
    div.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}
```

You can call this at the bottom of your JS file. If you need to clear localStorage you can manually call localStorage.clear(). For more information on localStorage api, you can check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

You can set something better like a "loggedIn": true or some other key value pair as well. When I read your question I read it as you wanted the contents of the div in the storage, but either would work in a similar fashion.

Comment: Exactly that, I thank you very much for your help, you really resolved the situation, my goal is to give access to a receipt form, only to those who have access to the password. You are incredible! thank you 

Comment: Awesome! Can you please mark the answer as accepted so that it's known that you don't need help with this anymore?